# Linq distinct by multiple columns and pick the newest row

Tags: linq

I have a data with multiple lines that are similar. They are latest results in games and for example if there are 3 goals that are scored in the game, that would mean 3 lines.

[image]

I want to distinct one game one line. But the distinct lines have to be the newest (firstOrDefault?)

I do want to show both status=Confirmed and status=Open but obviously i don´t want to show the same game both "Confirmed" and "Open"

So i want to group by both columns "Hometeam" and "outteam". But for same game I would get 3 lines if there were 3 goals but i want the "newest line".

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
data.GroupBy(d => new { Hometeam = d.Hometeam, Outteam = d.Outteam })
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(d => d.Status)
                  .ThenByDescending(d => d.GoalsHometeams + d.GoalsOutteams)
                  .First())
```

1. Groups by the team combinations
2. For each group, finds the entry with the newest status (`Confirmed` comes before `Open` in alphabetical order)
3. If multiple with same status (i.e., multiple `Open`), finds entry with highest combined score.
4. Grabs the first result (which should be newest) per group.

Demo: http://ideone.com/vlCtw

Sample Result:

```
Current game status results:
Confirmed, Fylkir, Valur, 3, 1
Confirmed, Selfoss, Grindavik, 3, 3
Confirmed, Keflavik, IBV, 1, 0
Confirmed, Stjarnan, IA, 1, 1
Confirmed, Breioablik, Fram, 0, 2
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, however i´m only getting results that contains status=open   see -> http://ideone.com/1GfRI   ???

Comment: @agh: It appears the language that the status is in for your real data set, open actually comes *before* confirmed in alphabetical order.  So to adapt my solution to your other language, you would need to order by status descending instead with `g.OrderByDescending(d => d.Status)`.  Then it should show the expected results.